# Solve mutual recursivity in comparison

Tags: antlr

How can I solve mutual recursivity in this case?

```
value : comparison | 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

comparison : value comparison_operator value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that its ambiguous as given.  What do you want it to do for an input like `A <op> B <op> C` where `<op>` is something that matches your comparison_operator rule?  If you want the equivalent of `A <op> (B <op> C)` then its quite easy:

```
primary: 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
comparison: primary | primary comparison_operator comparison;
value: comparison;
```

If you want something else, it becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed like so:

```
atom : variable | literal | call | constructor | (PARAM_START comparison PARAM_END);

comparison : (atom comparison_operator atom);

value : atom | comparison;
```